# GTK with Java on Windows

Tags: java, gtk

I searched for GTK java bindings and found java-gnome but java-gnome not support Windows os why ? is it possible to developing gtk apps with java-gnome on windows ?

Comment: https://github.com/JavaGtk/JavaGtk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-gnome); there is **no version available for Microsoft Windows** unlike most other `GTK+` bindings. So I'm afraid you cannot fulfill your purpose but you can do the same using [other languages](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php)